# SQL Server : matching records based on 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I am trying to match records between three tables, two tables being data to be matched, the third table is a central table telling me how records should be matched.

An example will be clearer than a long speech:

Table 1

```
Value1  A1  B1  C1
------------------
  0.1   1   b   z
  0.2   4   b   z
  1.1   5   b   z
  1.5   5   c   y
  2.5   7   c   x
```

Table 2

```
Value2  A2  B2  C2
------------------
  0.5   1   d   z
  0.7   4   d   z
  2.3   7   d   z
  1.7   5   e   y
  1.9   7   e   x
```

Table 3

```
    BL  BR  C
   -----------
     d   b  z
     c   e  x
     c   e  y
```

A way to see this is A represents holdings, C holders and B dates. So Table 1 tells me what holdings are at some dates, Table 2 tells me the same at some other dates and finally Table 3 tells me how to compare holdings, e.g. for holder C = z, I want to compare holdings between dates B = d and date B = b (in practice Table 1 and 2 are the same).

So what I look for is a table to compare holdings, taking into account holdings that were created and holdings that were deleted. I am looking for something like that:

```
Value1 A1  B1  C1  BR BL C  A2 B2 C2 Value2
-------------------------------------------
  0.1   1   b   z   b d  z  1   d  z  0.5
  0.2   4   b   z   b d  z  4   d  z  0.7
  1.1   5   b   z   b d  z
                    b d  z  7   d  z  2.3
  1.5   5   c   y   c e  y  5   e  y  1.7
  2.5   7   c   x   c e  x  7   e  x  1.9
```

So basically, records are matched only if A1 = A2, C1 = C2 and B1 = BR, B2 = BL, otherwise it is empty on one side or another.

I hope this is clear. I tried various approaches (left/righ/full joins) without success. Any help welcome!

Thanks

**EDIT**
Adding example code. This is T-SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1  (Value1 FLOAT, A1 INT, B1 CHAR, C1 CHAR);  
CREATE TABLE #T2 (Value2 FLOAT, A2 INT, B2 CHAR, C2 CHAR);  
CREATE TABLE #T3 (BR CHAR, BL CHAR, C CHAR);  

INSERT INTO #T1  VALUES (0.1, 1, 'b', 'z'), 
                (0.2, 4, 'b', 'z'), 
                (1.1, 5, 'b', 'z'), 
                (1.5, 5, 'c', 'y'), 
                (2.5, 7, 'c', 'x');

INSERT INTO #T2  VALUES (0.5, 1, 'd', 'z'), 
                (0.7, 4, 'd', 'z'), 
                (2.3, 7, 'd', 'z'), 
                (1.7, 5, 'e', 'y'), 
                (1.9, 7, 'e', 'x');

INSERT INTO #T3  VALUES ('b', 'd', 'z'), 
                    ('c', 'e', 'x'),
                    ('c', 'e', 'y');
```

Example query I tried.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM #T3 
LEFT JOIN #T1 ON #T1.B1 = #T3.BR AND #T1.C1 = #T3.C
FULL JOIN #T2 ON #T2.B2 = #T3.BL AND #T2.C2 = #T3.C AND #T2.A2 = #T1.A1
```

This is what I get [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYJSk.png). Close but I'd like BR, BL and C to never be NULL, because I have some logic after that on those columns. Those columns don't have to be null on the last row, it can be matched to a row in #T3.

The whole difficulty is in `AND #T2.A2 = #T1.A1`: if there exist such record I want it to match, but if not I would like it to behave as if the second join was a LEFT JOIN on `#T2.B2 = #T3.BL AND #T2.C2 = #T3.C`

**EDIT 2**
Thanks to Marlin Pierce post, here is a request that returns the result I look for:

```
SELECT Value1 A1,  B1,  C1,  BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2
FROM #T3 inner join #T1 on #T1.B1 = #T3.BR AND #T1.C1 = #T3.C
         inner join #T2 on #T2.B2 = #T3.BL AND #T2.C2 = #T3.C AND #T2.A2 = #T1.A1

UNION ALL

SELECT Value1 A1,  B1,  C1,  BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2
FROM #T3 left join #T2 on #T2.B2 = #T3.BL and #T2.C2 = #T3.C
         full join #T1 on #T1.B1 = #T3.BR and #T1.C1 = #T3.C AND #T2.A2 = #T1.A1
WHERE #T1.A1 is NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT Value1 A1,  B1,  C1,  BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2
FROM #T3 left join #T1 on #T1.B1 = #T3.BR and #T1.C1 = #T3.C
         full join #T2 on #T2.B2 = #T3.BL and #T2.C2 = #T3.C AND #T2.A2 = #T1.A1
WHERE #T2.A2 is NULL
```

However I'd like to find a more efficient/elegant way to do this, it it exists.

Comment: What SQL technology is this?  Post what you have tried for your queries.  Also you have 3 tables you are trying to get data from.  Try doing just 2 first then get data, then add the 3rd.

Comment: "I tried various approach".  Where's one of them?  I don't see it.  SO is not a free coding service website.  Post your query.  If it doesn't work, we will try to help.

Comment: Sounds like you need a FULL JOIN, please post your attempt to use that so we can debug it.

Comment: Added example codes. I tried various combination of joins without getting what I am looking for (which is the table written by hand in the first part of the message).

Comment: A clear description is clearer than an unclear description. Use enough words, sentences & references to examples to say what rows appear in the result in terms of the rows that appear in the input. Ie give the circumstances under which a row of the form (A1, B1, C1, BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2) appears in the result. Eg when a row (t1.A1, t1.B1, t1.C1) appears in T1 & A1=t1.A1 & B1=t1.B1 & C1=t1.C1 & ... OR ....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think this will give you the results you are looking for.  (What you are looking for is a little unclear.)

I don't know if there is a simpler solution, but there might not be, because you are looking for collapsing crossing combinations by rules of an inner join, but you need an outer join to include "missing" records.

```
SELECT Value1 A1,  B1,  C1,  BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2
FROM T3 inner join T1 on T1.B1 = T3.BR
        inner join T2 on T2.B2 = T3.BL
WHERE A1 = A2 and C1 = C2

UNION ALL

SELECT Value1 A1,  B1,  C1,  BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2
FROM T3 inner join T1 on T1.B1 = T3.BR
        left outer join T2 on T2.B2 = T3.BL
WHERE T2.B2 is NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT Value1 A1,  B1,  C1,  BR, BL, C,  A2, B2, C2, Value2
FROM T3 inner join T2 on T2.B2 = T3.BL
        left outer join T1 on T1.B1 = T3.BR
WHERE T1.B1 is NULL
```

Comment: The results will not include records from table T3 which do not match either T1 or T2, but I don't get the idea that you need those.

Comment: Hi. What you wrote is not exactly what I look for, but I got your idea and transformed it to the request I am searching for (see my edit). I am indeed looking for a solution which could be more elegant/efficient.